# How to remove rows of columns whose value count is less than particular number?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

df['Brand'].value_counts() gives list of occurrence of each value in column Brand. I want to remove all rows where the occurrence is less than 6. Column Brand is string.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibMIa.png)

Comment: Use: `df.value_counts()[df.value_counts().gt(6)]`

Comment: @Mayank seems wasteful to count twice ;) Use a variable

Comment: @mozway I know man. I thought of giving a one-liner, hence I did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Brand':[1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]})
df[df.apply(lambda x: df.value_counts()[x]>6)['Brand'].values]
```

Output:

[image]

A more efficient way, if your data size is huge:

```
temp = df.value_counts()>6
df[df['Brand'].isin(temp[temp].index.get_level_values(0).values)]
```

output:

[image]

Another way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Brand':[1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]})
temp = df['Brand'].tolist()
df[df['Brand'].apply(lambda x: temp.count(x)>6)]
```

with the same output.

Comment: Perfect. Your 2nd solution does work for me.

Comment: The first works, too. I edited that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this below;

```py
column = df['Brand'] > 6
valueCount = column.value_counts()
```

Comment: Brand column is a string. I table I posted is output for df['Brand'].value_counts()